# Remove column name suffix from DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas DataFrame in python:

| attr_x | header | example_x | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3232 | 322 | abv | ideo |
| 342 | 123213 | ffee | iie |
| 232 | 873213 | ffue | iie |
| 333 | 4534 | ffpo | iieu |

I want to remove the suffixes '_x' from all columns containing it. The original DataFrame is much longer. Example result:

| attr | header | example | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3232 | 322 | abv | ideo |
| 342 | 123213 | ffee | iie |
| 232 | 873213 | ffue | iie |
| 333 | 4534 | ffpo | iieu |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.removesuffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.removesuffix.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.removesuffix("_x")
```

Or `replace`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'_x$', '')
```

Comment: This for python 3.10 I believe